# jQuery/JavaScript - Repeating timer, save to MySQL upon reaching zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, timer

I'm working on a small project, that combines Java(servlets) with some web elements. I've got a Java back-end that deals with registration and login. When the user has logged in, he/she arrives at the dashboard where a timer awaits them.

The timer should be set at 25 minutes and when the user presses 'start', it should start counting down to zero. When zero has been reached, I want the timer to save the timestamps (begin/end) to MySQL and automatically start a 5 minute timer.

I've been looking on Google for quite some time. jQuery seems the easiest option, but I'm genuinely struggling getting this started.
Is there anyone who could help me?

Perhaps guide me on the right path or (if you have time) have a little coding session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On waiting page use Javascript:

```
var timeleft = 1500; // seconds left
var timer = setInterval(function () {
  timeleft--;
  // optional: update HTML element here
  if (timeleft == 0) { saveTimestamp(); clearInterval(timer); }
}, 1000); // run every second
```

Then make `saveTimestamp` function either redirect browser to another page or make ajax call to sync with server.

On server, make a check if user reached this point after less than 25 minutes, and if he didn't (no cheating), perform standard writing to SQL (I can't help you much with server-side, as I've never worked with Java servlets).

Comment: Thank you, this is the start I needed!